# Understanding html tags under rails to validate a form with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I am making my first steps with Javascript and fail to figure out the appropriate syntax for a simple form validation (I want to render an error if my text area "comments" is empty when the user click on "decline"). This is the code in my view in rails

```
<%= form_for (@account) do |f| %> 
<%= f.label :comments, "Comments" %> 
<%=f.text_area :comments %> 

<%= f.submit "Confirm", :name=>"conf" %> 
<%= f.submit "Decline (with comments)",:onclick=>"return(validate());" %> 
<% end %>
```

This is the html source code of my page

```
<form class="edit_account" id="edit_account_13" action="/accounts/13"accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" />
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="goWtQIV74wGXbbHIOM9hZTOftw90dl+/x43hxO0tnvoSGAFqcHmL/L3SIiVqkhe/yXWNMQZqILU9Saa/gxnCjA==" />
<label for="account_comments">Comments</label>
<textarea name="account[comments]" id="account_comments">
</textarea>

<input type="submit" name="conf" value="Confirm" />
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Decline (with comments)" onclick="return(validate());" />
```

In my javascripts folder I put the following code

```
function validate() { 
  //I have tried many other path to test this conditions but none of them worked
  if(document.forms.account_comments.value == "" ) { 
    alert( "Please provide something!" ); 
  } 
}
```

I know the function is called as I do get the alert if I remove the “if”. However, I do not manage to find the appropriate path/syntax to test that the text area is empty . Could anyone give me the appropriate syntax please and some hints on what html tag I should use (name?, id?) to manipulate them with Javascript? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not accessing the textarea correctly. You can select it as so:

```
function validate() {
  var textarea = document.getElementById('account_comments');
  if(textarea.value === "" ) { 
    alert( "Please provide something!" ); 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the element by id:

```
function validate() { 
  if((document.getElementById('account_comments').value) === "") {
    alert( "Please provide something!" ); 
  }
}
```